# How to find a unique index created for a table

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to insert a row into a Sybase ASE table, and I get a error saying,

```
Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object 'Employee' with unique index 'Employee_uk'
```

When I opened the DDL for the `Employee` table I don't see a unique constraint in it. So some other table's DDL is created with a unique index pointing to this Employee table.

How can I find which table is created with this unique index?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command:

```
sp_help Employee
```

to obtain all the information about the table.
This command can be used to get information on any database object.

Regards

Comment: I got a unique constraint Employee_pk after using sp_help but when I try to delete a row I get error saying a unique constraint Empoyee_uk is referenced.